# Since we do not have binding of redis cluster, How to run ycsb to test redis cluster?

Tags: ycsb, redis-cluster

I am doing research on redis. I have built my Redis cluster using three master nodes and I have another node for running ycsb. I encounter the same problem as described in 
[To start YCSB load with cluster enabled option for REDIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793976/to-start-ycsb-load-with-cluster-enabled-option-for-redis).
And I tried to edit RedisClient.java based on the answer given. However I got errors in :
import redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
,because those packages does not exsist. So my question is Where to find packages like redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster? Did anyone succeed in editing RedisClient.java for testing redis cluster, or do we have other solutions?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default redis client from ycsb does not support redis cluster. So to benchmark redis cluster using ycsb, we must mordify redis client(RedisClient.java) and re-comiple the code using maven. The following code worked for me:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2012 YCSB contributors. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you
 * may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You
 * may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License. See accompanying
 * LICENSE file.
 */

/**
 * Redis client binding for YCSB.
 *
 * All YCSB records are mapped to a Redis *hash field*.  For scanning
 * operations, all keys are saved (by an arbitrary hash) in a sorted set.
 */

package com.yahoo.ycsb.db;

import com.yahoo.ycsb.ByteIterator;
import com.yahoo.ycsb.DB;
import com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException;
import com.yahoo.ycsb.Status;
import com.yahoo.ycsb.StringByteIterator;


import redis.clients.jedis.Protocol;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

import redis.clients.jedis.HostAndPort;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * YCSB binding for <a href="http://redis.io/">Redis</a>.
 *
 * See {@code redis/README.md} for details.
 */
public class RedisClient extends DB {

  private JedisCluster jedis;

  public static final String HOST_PROPERTY = "redis.host";
  public static final String PORT_PROPERTY = "redis.port";
  public static final String PASSWORD_PROPERTY = "redis.password";

  public static final String INDEX_KEY = "_indices";

  public void init() throws DBException {
    Properties props = getProperties();
    int port;
    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();

    String portString = props.getProperty(PORT_PROPERTY);
    if (portString != null) {
      port = Integer.parseInt(portString);
    } else {
      port = Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT;
    }
    String host = props.getProperty(HOST_PROPERTY);

    jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort(host, port));

    jedis = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);


    String password = props.getProperty(PASSWORD_PROPERTY);
    if (password != null) {
      jedis.auth(password);
    }
  }

  public void cleanup() throws DBException {

  }

  /*
   * Calculate a hash for a key to store it in an index. The actual return value
   * of this function is not interesting -- it primarily needs to be fast and
   * scattered along the whole space of doubles. In a real world scenario one
   * would probably use the ASCII values of the keys.
   */
  private double hash(String key) {
    return key.hashCode();
  }

  // XXX jedis.select(int index) to switch to `table`

  @Override
  public Status read(String table, String key, Set<String> fields,
      HashMap<String, ByteIterator> result) {
    if (fields == null) {
      StringByteIterator.putAllAsByteIterators(result, jedis.hgetAll(key));
    } else {
      String[] fieldArray =
          (String[]) fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]);
      List<String> values = jedis.hmget(key, fieldArray);

      Iterator<String> fieldIterator = fields.iterator();
      Iterator<String> valueIterator = values.iterator();

      while (fieldIterator.hasNext() && valueIterator.hasNext()) {
        result.put(fieldIterator.next(),
            new StringByteIterator(valueIterator.next()));
      }
      assert !fieldIterator.hasNext() && !valueIterator.hasNext();
    }
    return result.isEmpty() ? Status.ERROR : Status.OK;
  }

  @Override
  public Status insert(String table, String key,
      HashMap<String, ByteIterator> values) {
    if (jedis.hmset(key, StringByteIterator.getStringMap(values))
        .equals("OK")) {
      jedis.zadd(INDEX_KEY, hash(key), key);
      return Status.OK;
    }
    return Status.ERROR;
  }

  @Override
  public Status delete(String table, String key) {
    return jedis.del(key) == 0 && jedis.zrem(INDEX_KEY, key) == 0 ? Status.ERROR
        : Status.OK;
  }

  @Override
  public Status update(String table, String key,
      HashMap<String, ByteIterator> values) {
    return jedis.hmset(key, StringByteIterator.getStringMap(values))
        .equals("OK") ? Status.OK : Status.ERROR;
  }

  @Override
  public Status scan(String table, String startkey, int recordcount,
      Set<String> fields, Vector<HashMap<String, ByteIterator>> result) {
    Set<String> keys = jedis.zrangeByScore(INDEX_KEY, hash(startkey),
        Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, recordcount);

    HashMap<String, ByteIterator> values;
    for (String key : keys) {
      values = new HashMap<String, ByteIterator>();
      read(table, key, fields, values);
      result.add(values);
    }

    return Status.OK;
  }

}
```

I think that may be helpful for others:)